# Python: How to split txt file data into csv according to user input

Tags: python, csv, read-write

So I am reading in a .txt file that is largely similar to this: TTACGATATACGA etc. but contains thousands of characters. Now I can read in a file and output it as a csv according to user input that decides characters per column and number of columns however it writes a new file for each time.

Ideally I would like to have a format such as such per file:

User enters 4 and 3.

Output: TCAG, TGCT, TACG,

My curent output is this:

TCAGTGCTTACG

I have tried looking at string splitting but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

here is what I've written thus far, apologies if it's poor:

```
#user input for parameters
user_input_character = int(input("Enter how many characters you;d like 

per column"))
user_input_column = int(input("Enter how many columns you'd like"))
character_per_column = user_input_character
columns_per_entry = user_input_column
characters_to_read = int((character_per_column * columns_per_entry))
print("Total characters: " + str(characters_to_read))

#counts used to set letters to be taken into intake
index_start = 0
index_finish = characters_to_read
count =1

#open the file to be read
lines = []
test_file = open("dna.txt", "r")
for line in test_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

lines.append(',')

#read the file and take note of its size for index purposes
read_file = test_file.read()
file_size = read_file.__len__()
print((file_size))
i = 1
index = 0
#use loop to make more than one file output
while(index < 50):

#print count used to measure progress for testing
    print('the count is', count)
    count += 1
    index += characters_to_read
    print('index: ',index)

#intake only uses letters from index count per file
    intake = read_file[index_start:index_finish]
    print(intake)

    index_start += characters_to_read
    index_finish +=characters_to_read

#output a txt file with the 4 letters from intake as a individually     numbered txt file
    text_file_output = open("Output%i.csv"%i,'w')
    i += 1
    text_file_output.write(intake)
    text_file_output.close()
#define path to print to console for file saving
    path = os.path.abspath("Output%i")
    directory = os.path.dirname(path)
    print(path)

test_file.close()
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your question is. What's wrong with what your code does? Are you asking how to split the intake chars into columns? How come you're only writing one line of data to each file?

Comment: I do apologise for the lack of clarity, I need the new written files for a dissertation project. At the moment when I use this code the output is just the whole string e.g. TCGAGAGACTCTAAACG, instead of splitting it into something like: TCAG, TAGC, CGAT etc.  My main problem may come from using this with excel as ideally I want the csv's to writen into their own cells, which I'm sure is possible.

Comment: Ok. Splitting a string into chunks is easy. But I still don't understand why you need all those separate little files. Why not a single normal CSV file, which Excel will happily read? I can see a few ways to improve your existing code, but it would help if you explain the structure of the input data. It looks like it can contain blank lines. Do the lines only contain letters, or can they also contain spaces?

Comment: Yeah you're right, the individual files writing was just for my own testing purposes. Ideally I would like to be able to write the file as such: TCAG, ACGT, TCAG (then a new line and the same again until the data input has run out). Essentially the input of data is just a long txt file which may have spaces and new lines that I will need to get rid of or ignore for the output.

Comment: Adding the commas is very easy, it's just a slight change to the `join` call. Do you want a comma at the end of each line? Dealing with whitespace in the input isn't hard, but it will slow things down a little. How big are these files? If they're small enough to read the whole thing in one go, that makes it quite simple.

Comment: ideally the output format will be in excel and just showing the character chunks in each cell without any commas visible so the csv output doesn't matter to me really. I'm not sure how excel and csv interact with each other quite yet so formatting might be necassary. The file sizes are around 10kb of plain text data I believe. I'm working with test data at 7kb and I can't say for sure the final size I will be dealing with.

Comment: Ok. I haven't used Excel for a while, so I'm a little hazy on the details. It can easily read proper CSV that uses commas, but I don't _think_ it needs them. 10 kilobytes is nothing, and even 10 megabytes is rather small on modern machines. If the files were gigabytes in size then we probably wouldn't want to read the whole thing into RAM. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to split your DNA data into rows consisting of columns and chunks of specified sizes. It assumes that the DNA data is in a single string with no white space characters (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc).

To test this code, I create some fake data using the `random` module.

```
from random import seed, choice
seed(42)

# Make some random DNA data
num = 66
data = ''.join([choice('ACGT') for _ in range(num)])
print(data, '\n')

# Split the data into chunks, columns and rows
chunksize, cols = 4, 3

row = []
for i in range(0, len(data), chunksize):
    chunk = data[i:i+chunksize]
    row.append(chunk)
    if len(row) == cols:
        print(' '.join(row))
        row = []
if row:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

**output**

```
AAGCCCAATAAACCACTCTGACTGGCCGAATAGGGATATAGGCAACGACATGTGCGGCGACCCTTG

AAGC CCAA TAAA
CCAC TCTG ACTG
GCCG AATA GGGA
TATA GGCA ACGA
CATG TGCG GCGA
CCCT TG
```

On my old 2GHz 32 bit machine, running Python 3.6.0, this code can process and save to disk around 100000 chars per second (that includes the time taken to generate the random data).

---

Here's a version of the above code that handles spaces and blank lines in the input data. It reads the input data from a file and writes the output to a CSV file.

Firstly, here's the code I used to create some fake test data, which I saved to "dnatest.txt".

```
from random import seed, choice, randrange
seed(123)

# Make some random DNA data containing spaces
pool = 'ACGT' * 5 + ' '
for _ in range(15):
    # Choose a random line length
    size = randrange(50, 70)
    data = ''.join([choice(pool) for _ in range(size)])
    print(data)
    # Randomly add a blank line
    if randrange(5) < 2:
        print()
```

Here's the file it created:

#### dnatest.txt

```None
AGCATCACCGGCCAGCGTCACGTAGAGGTCGAAACCGTATCCGATGT AGG

 ACC TTACTAC CGTACGGCAGGAGGAGGG TATTACAC CT TCTCACGAGCAAGGAATA
ATTGATGGCACAGC AAGATCCGCTA  CCGATTG CAACCA CATACGAT CGACCAGATGG
ACAGAACAGATCTTGGGAATGGAACAGGAGAGAGTGTGGGCCACATTAAAGTGATAAT ATTT
TCTGTCGTGGGGCACCAAACCATGCTAATGCACGACTGGGT GAGGGTTGAGAGCCTACTATCCTCAG
TCGATCGAGATGACCCTCCTATCGCAACAGCTGTCAGTGTCCAGAG ACGTCGC CA
TAGGTCTGGAAAC GCACTCCCCTC GGAATAGTCTACACGAGTCCATTATGTC
GATCTGACTATGGGGACCATAACGGCTATGCGACCATGGACTGGTTCGAG

GATTCCCGTTCTACAT CACCTT ACCTCTGATAA CGACTGGTTCGA GGGTCTC CC

AAA CGTCTATTATGTCATAACGTAACTCTGC CGTAGTTTGATCAAACGTACAGCCACCAC

TGAAGC CGCCTCGAACCGCGTCCGACCCTGGGGAGCCTGGGGCCCAGCA
CCTTAGC ACTGCGA AGCTACACCCCACGAGTAATTTG T CTATCGT CCG
GCCTCGTTTCCTTGTGAAATTAT ATGGT C AGTCTTCAATCAA CACCTA CTAATAA
 GTGCTAGC CCGGGGATCTTGTCCTGGTCCA GGTC AT AATCCGTGCTCAAATTACATGGCTT
TTAGTAATGAGTTCGGGC  GCGCCCTCAAAGTTGGTCTAGAAGCGCGCAGTTTTCCTTAGGT
```

Here's the code that processes that data:

```
# Input & output file names
iname = 'dnatest.txt'
oname = 'dnatest.csv'

# Read the data and eliminate all whitespace
with open(iname) as f:
    data = ''.join(f.read().split())

# Split the data into chunks, columns and rows
chunksize, cols = 4, 3

with open(oname, 'w') as f:
    row = []
    for i in range(0, len(data), chunksize):
        chunk = data[i:i+chunksize]
        row.append(chunk)
        if len(row) == cols:
            f.write(', '.join(row) + '\n')
            row = []
    if row:
        f.write(', '.join(row) + '\n')
```

And here's the file it creates:

#### dnatest.csv

```None
AGCA, TCAC, CGGC
CAGC, GTCA, CGTA
GAGG, TCGA, AACC
GTAT, CCGA, TGTA
GGAC, CTTA, CTAC
CGTA, CGGC, AGGA
GGAG, GGTA, TTAC
ACCT, TCTC, ACGA
GCAA, GGAA, TAAT
TGAT, GGCA, CAGC
AAGA, TCCG, CTAC
CGAT, TGCA, ACCA
CATA, CGAT, CGAC
CAGA, TGGA, CAGA
ACAG, ATCT, TGGG
AATG, GAAC, AGGA
GAGA, GTGT, GGGC
CACA, TTAA, AGTG
ATAA, TATT, TTCT
GTCG, TGGG, GCAC
CAAA, CCAT, GCTA
ATGC, ACGA, CTGG
GTGA, GGGT, TGAG
AGCC, TACT, ATCC
TCAG, TCGA, TCGA
GATG, ACCC, TCCT
ATCG, CAAC, AGCT
GTCA, GTGT, CCAG
AGAC, GTCG, CCAT
AGGT, CTGG, AAAC
GCAC, TCCC, CTCG
GAAT, AGTC, TACA
CGAG, TCCA, TTAT
GTCG, ATCT, GACT
ATGG, GGAC, CATA
ACGG, CTAT, GCGA
CCAT, GGAC, TGGT
TCGA, GGAT, TCCC
GTTC, TACA, TCAC
CTTA, CCTC, TGAT
AACG, ACTG, GTTC
GAGG, GTCT, CCCA
AACG, TCTA, TTAT
GTCA, TAAC, GTAA
CTCT, GCCG, TAGT
TTGA, TCAA, ACGT
ACAG, CCAC, CACT
GAAG, CCGC, CTCG
AACC, GCGT, CCGA
CCCT, GGGG, AGCC
TGGG, GCCC, AGCA
CCTT, AGCA, CTGC
GAAG, CTAC, ACCC
CACG, AGTA, ATTT
GTCT, ATCG, TCCG
GCCT, CGTT, TCCT
TGTG, AAAT, TATA
TGGT, CAGT, CTTC
AATC, AACA, CCTA
CTAA, TAAG, TGCT
AGCC, CGGG, GATC
TTGT, CCTG, GTCC
AGGT, CATA, ATCC
GTGC, TCAA, ATTA
CATG, GCTT, TTAG
TAAT, GAGT, TCGG
GCGC, GCCC, TCAA
AGTT, GGTC, TAGA
AGCG, CGCA, GTTT
TCCT, TAGG, T
```

Comment: Wow, this looks exactly what I am trying to achieve, thank you so much for your help! My dissertation will thank you! It looks like changing the chunksize and cols to something that a user would choose is relatively easy just using input('how many...' etc.)

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I just wondered if you could help me to understand what is going on specifically here:         if len(row) == cols:
            f.write(', '.join(row) + '\n')
            row = []
    if row:
        f.write(', '.join(row) + '\n')

I understand that you are writing new rows but what I don't get is why there are identical if statements, surely one is enough? Also how is there no comma at the end of each row? Since you are joining ',' each time. Is that a formatting feature from python/csv?

Comment: @JRE The last two lines in that script are outside the `for` loop. The code in the `for` loop writes a row when it's got a complete row. So it's possible that when the `for` loop exits that there's stuff in `row`, and so we need to test if `row` isn't empty, and if it isn't we need to save that stuff to the file. If you want commas at the end of every row, just change the `'\n'` in the `write` calls to `',\n'`. Like this: `f.write(', '.join(row) + ',\n')`

Comment: I see. Thank you for taking the time to help me understand!